# Pre-guess size of Bitmap from the actual Uri, before scale-loading

Tags: android, android-camera, bitmapfactory

If you have a Uri and you need the `Bitmap`, you could theoretically do this

```
Bitmap troublinglyLargeBmp =
  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
      State.mainActivity.getContentResolver(), theUri );
```

but it will crash every time,

so you do this .........

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;

AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =null;
fileDescriptor =
  State.mainActivity.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor( theUri, "r");

Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap
  = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
    fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);

Utils.Log("'4-sample' method bitmap ... "
   +actuallyUsableBitmap.getWidth() +" "
   +actuallyUsableBitmap.getHeight() );
```

that's **fantastic** and is the working solution.

Notice the factor of "four" which tends to work well, in current conditions (2014) with typical camera sizes, etc. HOWEVER, it would be best to **guess or learn exactly the size of the image data at theUri**, and then using that information, **intelligently choose that factor**.

In short, **how to correctly choose that scale factor** when you load a Uri ?

Android experts, is this a well-known problem, is there a solution?  Thanks from your iOS->Android friends! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See the Android guide to [handling large bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Specifically this section:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

EDIT

In your case, you'll replace the `decodeResource` line with:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
```