# Failed to allocate memory android

Tags: android

Here I am getting failed to allocate memory in bitmap.Here i have attached code with logcat. Can any one give solution for it. I have declared bitmap is null even i am getting same error.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (phones != null) {
            Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
            if (phones.getCount() == 0) {
                Log.d("No Contacts", "No Contacts");
            }

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
               Bitmap bit_thumb = null;
                String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String image_thumb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                try {
                    if (image_thumb != null) {
                        bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                    } else {
                        Log.e("No Image Thumb", "--------------");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                selectUser.setThumb(bit_thumb);
                selectUser.setName(name);
                selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                selectUser.setCheckedBox();
                selectUsers.add(selectUser);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
        }
        //phones.close();
        return null;
    }
```

Log cat is

```
1-25 14:21:04.616 1502-1617/com.jamol.contacts E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 2073612 byte allocation with 347044 free bytes and 338KB until OOM"
    01-25 14:21:04.616 1502-1617/com.jamol.contacts D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
    01-25 14:21:04.616 1502-1617/com.jamol.contacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
      Process: com.jamol.contacts, PID: 1502
      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
       Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2073612 byte allocation with 347044 free bytes and 338KB until OOM
          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:863)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:839)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:877)
          at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:860)
          at com.jamol.contacts.MainActivity$LoadContact.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:549)
          at com.jamol.contacts.MainActivity$LoadContact.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:527)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the thing what are you doing is very bad.
You are trying to store the whole bitmap in the `SelectUser` instance.
Of course, I don't know your task, but just imagine. For now you can select only one user. Later, you will decide to add ability for multi-select users. You will select 20 user and you want store their thumbnails in memory?
It's very bad. Please, instead of this, store in `SelectUser` only URL or URI of your image. And then, when you need to display it, use one of this library:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

But, if you really need to get the bitmap, you should know, that your solution with `MediaStore` is outdated.

Use `BitmapFactory` instead.
You can read this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135522/1796309

> See the Android guide to [handling large bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).
>
> Specifically this section:
>
> ```
> BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
> options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
> BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
> int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
> int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
> String imageType = options.outMimeType;
> ```
>
> EDIT
>
> In your case, you'll replace the `decodeResource` line with:
>
> ```
> BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
> ```
>
> null, options);

## EDIT

Also, to load photos from contacts, you may check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240238/1796309

> This works for me:
>
> ```
> public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {
>     Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
>     InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
>     if (input == null) {
>         return null;
>     }
>     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
> }
> ```